# How to change Macro value in VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I migrated one VC++ project from VS2008 to VS2010, and some Macro value was changed. I want to change the value(e.g. $(TargetName)) back to match what I have in VS2008.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the Project name in Solution Explorer, the first page (Configuration Properties \ General) has the Target Name definition.

Comment: @Jess: I tried that w/o luck. I changed value for "Target Name" on the first page and saved the config, but I checked $(TargetName) not changing. I assume $(TargetName) and "Target Name" should match.

Comment: Where are you looking for $(TargetName)?  This value will be used by VS when compiling your code (typcially its the base filename for your .obj / .exe files).  Note, there are independent values for Debug, Release and other Configurations -- and also, it is only known to VS, it won't be available as a "blanket" environment variable.

Comment: @Jess: Thank you for your reply. After I change and save new value of "Target Name", then open configuration window again, select one of fields to edit, you would get the Macro list here. I see $(TargetName) value not changed.

Comment: The other fields are using this value (whatever you set ($TargetName) as part of their value.  You are actually changing ALL the objects that use ($TargetName) when you change that parameter -- its a macro to be used in other fields.  If you want to change specific fields, just edit them individually.

Comment: Do you have write-access to the project/solution file?